# How to Clone a Relative Layout in Android?

Tags: android, xml

this is my XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Paste Link Here"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i need to clone the inner part of code, i mean i want to create 4 row like first row , and i need to show this link and download button of inner relative layout 4 time,under the first one, like a list

how can i clone and show 5 of this relative view in my main page?

i want to copy this relative view just under the first one,and third one just under the second one and  ...

Comment: Have you ever thought about using a `ListView`?

Comment: Move 'to be cloned' layout to a separate XML, then use <include> tag to include layouts. unique IDs can be assigned to each included layout

Comment: @XaverKapeller No man

Comment: @AlexanderZhak if you know what i mean please post me answer

Comment: Do you have five items total? Or do you have more than 5 items?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk i just have 5 item , 5 of that relative view i want to show with a divider

Comment: its better to add them dynamically from code. Tomorrow you might think to give 6 or 8 download links... :)  Use addView() method

Answer (score 0):

Create a new row.xml to represent each row

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Paste Link Here"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then use  to replicate it in your main layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">
     <include layout="@layout/row" id="@+id/row1" />
     <include layout="@layout/row" id="@+id/row2" />
     <include layout="@layout/row" id="@+id/row3" />
     <include layout="@layout/row" id="@+id/row4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For more information on reusing android layouts, have a look here [Re-using layuts](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

As mentioned in a comment above, if you have no specific reason to do it this way, you should use a listview instead or a gridlayout or another UI element that fits your needs

Comment: i need to put them with space, but its not work correct, bcuz it put them on each other, not in the bottom of each other

Comment: Change the containaing RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. See my edits above

Answer (score 0):

its better to add them dynamically from code. Tomorrow you might think to give 6 or 8 download links... :) Use `addView()` method.

See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29